# WSO2 ESB - Connection Cancel exception 101507

Tags: java, salesforce, wso2, wso2-esb

Help me out to fix this issue.
I'm invoking a 'salesforce' api and when I'm waiting for the response I'm getting this exception.

Comment: 101507 means Connection Cancelled. Please provide the logs, You can enable wire logs. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Error+Handling

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Performance+Tuning

Increase the time to 90 seconds 
/wso2am-1.8.0/wso2am-1.8.0/repository/conf/nhttp.properties
snd_alive_sec=90

issue fixed ..